# What's the meaning of "come home to"

Tags: meaning

> I **came home** to a group of people who had got very fired up. They were ready and willing to work with the local council to see how much influence we could have in bringing the climate change issues into our policies.

> Students learn in a way that fuels their individual interest, but they **come home** to a group of friends who vary in major.

I don't understand *came/come home to*. What's the meaning of that phrase?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "came home to X", in these examples, means that the person involved has been away from home for some extended time. They haven't kept up with what has been happening at home in their absence, so what they encounter on returning there has some novelty to them.